# How do you determine a Record value's type when using the Neo4j 3.x BOLT driver?

Tags: neo4j

If I’m looking at a Record pulled from a StatementResult, what is the right way to determine the type of a particular value? I know Neo will try to coerce types for me but what if I want to know, for example, if something is a Node? There is a typeOf() method that you can call but I don’t see where I get the Value to pass to that method. For example in the following snippet how do I determine the type of the value held by key?

```
StatementResult statementResult = session.run(cypher,paramMap);
Record record = single();
record.get('key').type().isTypeOf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
boolean isNumber = record.get("key").type().equals(session.typeSystem().NUMBER());
```

See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/blob/1.0/driver/src/main/java/org/neo4j/driver/v1/types/TypeSystem.java for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think Stefan's answer is perfectly valid, however it will bound your code to the v1 of the protocol.

I would use the internal namespace in order to keep it working in further versions, for eg :

```
import static org.neo4j.driver.internal.types.InternalTypeSystem.TYPE_SYSTEM;

if ( record.get( "key" ).hasType( TYPE_SYSTEM.NODE() ) {
  // it is a node
}
```

From what I can see in the driver test, it is the same usage :

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/blob/1.1/driver/src/test/java/org/neo4j/driver/v1/types/TypeSystemTest.java#L210

Comment: Thanks but I'm always very nervous of using anything labeled internal